# Inside Interceptor.intercept(), how do I know if the Action has already been executed?

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor

I'm implementing some stuff in my Struts-based application using interceptors, and I'm getting confused about how their lifecycle works. According to the Struts docs (["Interceptors"](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.8/docs/interceptors.html), ["Writing interceptors"](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.8/docs/writing-interceptors.html) and ["Big picture"](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.8/docs/big-picture.html)), it should work something like this:

```
FirstInterceptor
  NextInterceptor
    LastInterceptor
      Action
      Result
    LastInterceptor
  NextInterceptor
FirstInterceptor
```

which makes sense, but I'm stumbling on how to distinguish an interceptor call executing before the action from one executing after the result is rendered (I'm skipping `PreResultListener`s here). <strike>If I fire up a debugger, I get two calls to `intercept()` and can't find anything too obvious on the `ActionInvocation` I'm being passed.</strike> *(**Update**: This part was a major confusion on my end, and I was able to answer my question below once I got it)*

The ["Big picture"](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.8/docs/big-picture.html) page talks somewhat confusingly of a "before" and "after" "clause" that are called, but I don't know what to make of it:

> [...]
>
> This includes invoking any Interceptors (the before clause) in advance of invoking the Action itself.
>
> [...]
>
> Interceptors are executed again (in reverse order, calling the after clause).
>
> [...]

*(**Update**: These two sentences are still bad, though)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no two calls to the interceptor:

```
public class MyInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) {
        /*
        This is before Action.execute(),
        and before all interceptors down the stack
        */

        String code = invocation.invoke();

        /*
        This is after Action.execute(),
        the result rendering and all
        interceptors down the stack,
        but before the interceptors
        higher up in the stack.
        */

        return code;
    }

}
```

*(Note that the "two calls to intercept" I was witnessing in the debugger were a result of a less obvious redirect that I failed to notice. This confused me a lot.)*